# Converting dataframe columns into list of tuples

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, tuples

I have:

```
val DF1 = sparkSession.sql("select col1,col2,col3 from table");
val tupleList = DF1.select("col1","col2").rdd.map(r => (r(0),r(1))).collect()

tupleList.foreach(x=> x.productIterator.foreach(println))
```

But I do not get all the tuples in the output. Where is the issue?

```
col1 col2
AA  CCC
AA  BBB 
DD  CCC 
AB  BBB 
Others  BBB 
GG  ALL 
EE  ALL 
Others  ALL 
ALL BBB 
NU FFF 
NU  Others 
Others  Others 
C   FFF
```

The output I get is: 
    `CCC AA BBB AA Others AA Others DD ALL Others ALL GG ALL ALL`

Comment: Before you wonder, check what `tuple.productIterator.foreach(println)` gives you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
scala> val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
scala> val df1 = hiveContext.sql("select id, name from class_db.students")
scala> df1.show()
+----+-------+
|  id|   name|
+----+-------+
|1001|   John|
|1002|Michael|
+----+-------+

scala> df1.select("id", "name").rdd.map(x => (x.get(0), x.get(1))).collect()
res3: Array[(Any, Any)] = Array((1001,John), (1002,Michael))
```

Comment: Maybe add prose "convert the `DataFrame` to `RDD` and then map to a tuple".

Comment: I get "invalid syntax" :(

Answer (score 0):

To resolve invalid syntax issue in pyspark use

```
temp = df1.select('id','name').rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1])).collect()
```